# Scope not seeing passed params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, scope, arguments

I'm getting this error

> "wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)"

But if I run `pry` in the controller or the scope I can see the params and they are being passed in. I've searched everywhere but can't figure out why this is happening.

**Controller**

```
def create
  if Conversation.between(params[:sender_id], params[:recipient_id]).present?
    @conversation = Conversation.between(params[:sender_id],
    params[:recipient_id]).first
  else
    @conversation = Conversation.create!(conversation_params)
  end
end
```

**Model**

```
scope :between, -> (sender_id, recipient_id) { where(sender_id: sender_id, recipient_id: recipient_id).or.where(sender_id: recipient_id, recipient_id: sender_id) }
```

Like I said if I pry in either place I can see the params are there and they're being passed in. Maybe it has something to do with my scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Rails 5? If you are, I think you're missing an argument to `or`. If you change your scope to something like this, it should work. Your second where clause should be the argument given to `or`.

```
scope :between, -> (sender_id, recipient_id) { where(sender_id: sender_id, recipient_id: recipient_id).or(where(sender_id: recipient_id, recipient_id: sender_id)) }
```

The [official documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#or-conditions) shows it like this:

```
Client.where(locked: true).or(Client.where(orders_count: [1,3,5]))
```

Comment: Thanks...that seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
scope :between, ->(params) {where(sender_id: params[:sender_id], recipient_id: params[:recipient_id]).or.where(sender_id: params[:recipient_id], recipient_id: params[:sender_id])
```

And then you'd have to call it with:

```
 Conversation.between( { sender_id: params[:sender_id], recipient_id: params[:recipient_id]).present?
```